# how to use android v3 apk sign system

Tags: android, android-app-signing

If you lost your signing keys, you decided to use v3 key rotation apk signature system, it won't work on older Android versions, right? 
what will happen ? will the app fails to update on older versions when you push an update to play store.

Comment: @MartinZeitler no, the v3 allows us to change signing keys as part of update. https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v3

Comment: `app's older signing certs which the app itself still trusts` probably already answers the question then... because the previous keys would still be contained.

Comment: @MartinZeitler does that mean that i still need old certificates ? i dont know how this mechanism helps when they previous sign keys are lost.

Comment: as it seems, they are still known to Google and will be embedded, for the backwards compatibility - else it certainly wouldn't work without a full uninstall. but alike this, I see no issue.